# Python: Creating nested attributes

Tags: python, selenium, autocomplete

I will begin by describing my goal because chances are I am barking up the wrong tree.

Using selenium, we are using these around 400 Javascript OnClick snippets to navigate around an internal website for various tasks.  Using a python script, I am able to extract this OnClick data from the web page and put them into any python format needed.

There's around 10 projects that would be relying on this.  Therefore the hope is to be able to import this into all of my projects so I only have a single script to update (should the page change in the future).

This is what I am aiming for.  In another script a user could enter:

```
    webdriver.execute_script(x.Logout.Home)
```

The important part is x.Logout.Home.  In this case, x is the name of the library I am creating.

x.Logout.Home would return a string.  "Logout" is the name of the link I am trying to navigate to and "Home" is the menu that Logout is under.  I need to do this because within the 400 links, there are conflicting names- so there needs to be a way to tell them apart.

The idea is that when one of my coworkers is trying navigate to a certain page within our environment, they can just start typing the name of the link they want and it will auto-complete it for them.

---

I have tried playing around with classes and objects.  In my adventure I tried many variations of:

```
    class x:
         def __init__(self, PageName, OnClick)
              setattr(self, PageName, OnClick)
```

Which sort of gets me there.  But sadly, this is not possible:

```
    class x:
         def __init__(self, PageName, PageMenu, OnClick)
              setattr(self, PageName, PageMenu, OnClick)
```

Any ideas?  I don't mind reading for the answer if someone links me to the material.

Comment: Something like `x.Logout.Home` is evaluated as `(x.Logout).Home`, and you can't change this.  This means that `x` does not know about `Home`; `x` only knows about `Logout`, and the *result* of `x.Logout` is what knows about `Home`.  So what you would need to do is create a custom class and make `(x.Logout)` returns an instance of that class, and that object then knows how to get the right value for its `Home` attribute.  If you search for things like "Python nested attributes" or "Python multiple dots in attribute" you can find other questions about this.

Comment: I'd mark you as the answer because you gave me exactly what I needed.  For anyone in the future- based on Bren's answer I gleaned that I could not have an "auto populate" because I would have to execute "x.Logout" to get "Home".  Therefore I just made a class and added the OnClick data into seperate variables.